# Shift array in stateflow

Tags: arrays, matlab, simulink, shift, stateflow

I want to shift an array within stateflow by one element.

In matlab, I would use *circshift* or this code:

```
>> x = [1:5]
x =
     1     2     3     4     5
>> x(2:end) = x(1:end-1)
x =
     1     1     2     3     4
>> x(1) = 0 % New Value
x =
     0     1     2     3     4
```

How can I implement this in stateflow action language.
Embedded matlab-function is not possible because of realtime-target.

I tried this:

```
{x[2:end] = x[1:end-1];
x[1] = 0;}
```

but thats a syntax error.
For loop should be possible as well, but thats strange to me in matlab :-)

Thanks in advance

Comment: A MATLAB Function (what you call Embedded MATLAB) is possible for a real-time target. In fact, that's precisely what they are designed for.

Comment: @am304, agreed. You could also consider using [MATLAB as the action language](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stateflow/ug/modify-the-action-language-for-a-chart.html) for your Stateflow chart since [`circshift` supports code generation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--alphabetical-list.html)

Answer (score 0):

Both answers in comments helped a lot: Matlab Function works also with my target and circshift works fine.